# Question on whether a set is measurable

Tags: measure-theory

> Let $A$ be a non-Lebesgue measurable set, and let $B=[0,1]\subseteq\mathbb{R}$. Show that $C=A\times B$ is non-measurable.

I try use the regularity of the lebesgue measure, but don´t work,
maybe take a set of borel sets and suppose $C$ is measurable give something..

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You might use this result.   If $C\subseteq [0,1]^2$ is product Borel measurable, then
the section sets
$$A_x = \{s\in [0,1]| (x,s)\in C\}$$
are measurable.

If $C$ is product Lebesgue mesurable, then the $A_x$ are measurable almost everywhere.

Comment: but A is'nt in [0,1]

Comment: This will work if the first factor is the real line.  It is a general property of measure spaces.